# Many to many relationship in my database design

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2007, database-schema

I have a very simple database design which I have made so far.One problem I am facing now is following scenario.

A Student can have multiple subjects and a subject can be taken by multiple students.I am not being able to join the following tables

```
1.Student
2.Student_Subject
3.Subject
```

Where I am mistaking here...........[image: Class DataBase Design]

Comment: I think you must connect `Student>ID` with `Student_Subject>St_ID` and `Subject>ID` with `Student_Subject>Sub_ID` .

Comment: You said ID from Student table should be joined to St_ID in Student_Subject.Why not St_ID in Student Table should be mapped with St-ID in Student_Subject Table I did this but access is not allowing this ?

Comment: I'll post an answer to make it clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You must connect `Student>ID` with `Student_Subject>St_ID` and `Subject>ID` with `Student_Subject>Sub_ID`.

You will need to do this because the relation between `Student` table and `Subject` table is many-to-many. and you must split it into 2 relations 1-to-many and many-to-one. That is one of the main rules in making `SQL` relations.

and in this case you won't need `Student>st_Id` since `Student>Id` will store the student's ID.it's the same with `Subject>Sub_id`.

Now, when a student has many courses you will need to add a new field to `Student_Subject` with the ID of the student in `St_ID` and the ID of the course in `Sub_ID`. the same will happen for a course with many students.

In both cases, you will only add fields to `Student_Subject` table.

you can google more about SQL relations.